# Magento 2.1.9 - Custom Module tab not showing

Tags: magento2, admin, system.xml, acl

I have followed different posts in order to get the solution and the tab working, but It doesn't show up.

I have followed this ones:

[Custom admin configuration tab not showing Magento CE 2.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135489/custom-admin-configuration-tab-not-showing-magento-ce-2-1)

[Magento Custom Module Not Showing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190383/magento-custom-module-not-showing)

Not even the ones that they put as an example, here is the code:

[image]

module.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MSP_ReCaptcha" setup_version="1.4.11"/>
</config>
```

acl.xml

```
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="MSP_ReCaptcha::config" title="Google ReCaptcha" sortOrder="50" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

system.xml:

```
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="msp_tab" translate="label" sortOrder="1000">
            <label>MSP_SECURITY</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="msp_securitysuite_recaptcha" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1"
                 showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Google ReCaptcha</label>
            <tab>msp_tab</tab>
            <resource>MSP_ReCaptcha::config</resource>

            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1"
                   showInStore="1">
                <label>General</label>
                <field >
                    <!-- lots of code -->
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

I run these commands:

```
rm -rf pub/static/*;
php bin/magento setup:upgrade;
php bin/magento cache:flush;
```

Comment: Where do you want this tab?

Comment: I would like to have the tab inside: 

Stores -> Configuration -> And then either in General or if there is the option; create a tab called Security and put in there the Google ReCaptcha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting this to show up in the Configuration section it looks right at first glance. Did you log out of the Admin and then back in?

Comment: I have tried and no changes anywhere..

Answer (score 1):

In the end it was just a newbie mistake.  All my files were in local and not all of them did sync with remote server, so I didn't have all files correctly on remote where I could see the changes.